# Parsing multipart HTTP form data with file upload content using Scala

Tags: parsing, scala

There are plenty of [multipart/form-data](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt) file upload solutions out there, but I have not been able to find a free standing one for Scala.

Play2 has this functionality as part of the framework and Spray also supports multipart form data. Unfortunately both these appear to be fairly integrated into the rest of the toolsets (I may be wrong here).

My server has been developed using Finagle (which does not currently support multipart form data), and if possible I would like to use a free standing lib or 'roll my own' solution.

This is a typical multipart/form-data message:

```
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1"

First parameter content
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value2"

Second parameter content
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

$%^&#$%^%#$
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--
```

In this example, `*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary` is the form boundary, so the multipart upload contains 2 text parameters and one image (I concatenated the image data for clarity).

If someone who knows Scala better than me can give me a bit of a rundown on how to approach parsing this content, I will be very grateful.

To start with, I thought I would quickly split the content in three doing:

```
data.split("\\Q--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary\\E") foreach println
```

But execution is notably slow (update - this was due to warm up time). Is there a more efficient way to split the parts? My strategy is to split the content into parts, and the split the parts into sub-parts. Is this a crappy approach? I've seen similar problems being solved with state machines? What is a good functional approach. Keep in mind, I'm trying to learn a proper a approach to Scala while trying to solve the problem.

**Update:**

I really thought a solution to this problem would be a line or two in Scala. If someone stumbles over this question with a slick solution, please take the time to jot it down. From my understanding one could parse this message using pattern matching, parsing combinators, extraction or simply splitting the string. I'm trying to find the best way to solve this kind of problem, as a project I'm working involves a lot of natural language parsing, and I need to write my own custom parsing tools. I'm getting a good understanding of Scala, but nothing beats the advice of an expert.

It's not just about solving the problem, it's about finding the best (and hopefully simplest) possible way to solve this type of problem.

Comment: You can find the Play code here https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala It seems reasonably understandable

Comment: Thank @Paul. I had a look at the play code, thanks for the link. I do understand most of it, however, it's a bit complicated for what I'm trying to do. I'm just looking for the simplest way to break apart the three data packets above and access each packet's content. Some sort of a nested split based on regular expressions may do the trick?

Comment: I would suggest retitling this question - I've ignored it for a while as being specific to file upload and things, whereas it seems to be a general question on parsing. I've retagged to indicate this, but a title that makes clear it's about writing a parser will probably attract more replies.

Comment: You have a good point, thanks @submonoid. I changed the heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the worst possible solution, and not scalable in any way, but to quickly just get the image data from the multipart request I did the following (if someone gives a better answer, I'll unmark my answer):

```
// Take the request and split it into parts
var requestParts = request.content.toString(UTF_8).split("\\Q--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary\\E")
// Split the third part at the blank line
val imageParts = requestParts(3).split("\\n\\s*\\n")
// The part above the blank line is the header text
val imageHeader = imageParts(0)
// The part below the blank line is the image body
val imageBodyString = imageParts(1)
```

I'll try to improve on this later, but have to push ahead for now. Another day, another project :-o

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious about how slow your "notably slow" actually is. I wrote the following simple little function to generate fake messages:

```
def generateFakeMessage(n: Int) = {
  val rand = new scala.util.Random(1L)
  val maxLines = 100
  val maxLength = 100

  (1 to n).map(i =>
    "--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary\n" +
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"value%d\"\n\n".format(i) +
    (0 to rand.nextInt(maxLines)).map(_ =>
      (0 to rand.nextInt(maxLength)).map(_ => rand.nextPrintableChar).mkString
    ).mkString("\n")
  ).mkString("\n") + "\n--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--"
}
```

Next I created a reasonably large message to use for testing:

```
val data = generateFakeMessage(10000)
```

It ends up containing a little over half a million lines. Then I tried your regular expression:

```
data.split("\\Q--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary\\E").size
```

And it returns more or less instantaneously. You could probably tune the regular expression a bit, and there are cleaner approaches you could use if your data were an `Iterable[String]` over the lines of the message, but I don't think you're going to get better performance from a hand-rolled state machine for parsing one big `String`.

Comment: Thank you Travis. I was being silly and tested my code as a Scala script. I did not realize it kept incurring a start-up penalty. It is actually very impressive to see how fast your code executes. I'm keeping the question open in the hope that someone will give me  guidance on my parsing problem. Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

For a first suggestion, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194445/how-to-parse-line-based-text-file-mht-in-scala-way) gives two suggestions, one using a state machine, and the other using parser combinators. I'd pay especial attention to the answer using parser combinators, since these provide a very easy way to build up this sort of parser. The syntax provided in Daniel's answer should adapt very easily to your situation.

Further, you can provide more specific mappings into Scala for your particular grammar if you require. Where Daniel has:

> def field = (fieldName <~ ":") ~ fieldBody <~ CRLF ^^ { case name ~ body => name -> body }

you can replace this with an alternation pattern over multiple fields (`contentType|contentDisposition|....`) and map each of these individually into your Scala objects.

Apologies for not having the time to write a more detailed solution here, but this should hopefully point you in the right direction!

Comment: I've not used parser combinators before, but now is as good a time as any, I suppose ;-) I did stumble over that solution after asking this question, but the question had the constraint of not wanting to load the whole file into memory. I don't have this constraint, so thought there may have been a better way. I'm really looking for a simple solution, because I know there must be one. In the meantime, I'll give it another look though, thanks, and thanks for the advice. I just want to be certain I've explored all avenues, because I need to do a lot of parsing in an upcoming project.

Comment: For a really simple solution, you're probably fine with your splitting method. Where combinators come in handy is in building up complex parsers from very simple ones. Whilst those given in Daniel's answer might look complex, each individual part is very simple, so you can build up to a parser from pieces rather than trying to grok the whole grammer at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your solution:

```
data.split("\\Q--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary\\E") foreach println
```

which is O(n) in complexity, is the best and the simplest you can get. As Travis previously said, this manipulation is not slow. As always with a multipart HTTP form, you will have to parse it one way or another and doing better to O(n) seems tricky.

Moreover, as `split` provides you an `Iterable` it is really perfect for any matching, treatment...