# Saving an image received as part of multipart form data using Scala

Tags: image, scala

My server receives multipart form data from a mobile app. The result of printing out the request using request.content.toString(UTF_8) is shown below. The image is sent by the mobile as a base64-encoded string. How do I save the image data to file?

```
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1"

Furniture
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value2"

Chair
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����JFIF��XExifMM*�i...rest of image goes here...
--*****org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--
```

Comment: We can better help you with your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). The `toString` output you pasted is basically gibberish, other than Googling for JFIF turns up [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format).

Comment: I posted a link to the Play! code in the other question you've already asked about this same issue.

Comment: And here's a related question that should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194445/how-to-parse-line-based-text-file-mht-in-scala-way. But if you want us to help with your actual current issue, you're going to have to provide more information (and code) as @dave says

Comment: Although, just a guess, that data does not look like it's base64 encoded, unless something else already did the decoding for you.

Comment: @dave Thanks for the help. Apologies for not posting more code, but it was such a mess that I did not know where to start. I did manage to save the image now, thanks. Also, I had a look at the play code for parsing the multipart message, but I was hoping for something really simple to just help me split the content string into it's parts and extract their content fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am yet to parse the multipart form data, but saving the image turned out to be easy (once you know how). To test, I'm uploading only the image during testing using:

```
curl -T "image.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:8080/imageupload
```

I'm using Finagle, which depends on the netty libraries, so the request.content() returns a object of type org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer, for which you extract the image data as follows:

**To save the file from the request content to file:**

```
  val raf = new java.io.RandomAccessFile("image.jpg", "rw");
  val buf = request.getContent();
  val fChannel = raf.getChannel();

  fChannel.write( buf.toByteBuffer() );
  raf.close();
  fChannel.close();
```

**To *pass* the request content on to a web service expecting base64binary:**

```
  import org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil._
  import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.base64.Base64

  val base64binaryImage = (Base64.encode(request.getContent())).toString(UTF_8)
```